# How to get user ID's from multiple usernames?

Tags: loop, user-meta, array, users

I am trying to produce user ID's from multiple specific usernames. The usernames are pulled from a profile field, and any number of usernames will be called. I want the user ID's from each of the users to be put into the 'include' of $args like `'include' => array( 1, 2),`. What am I doing wrong?

```
// Search these Usernames
$usernames = array( user1, user2 );

// Fetch the User IDs
$prof_ids = array(); 
foreach ($usernames as $prof_id) {
    $user = get_user_by('user_login', $prof_id); 
    $prof_ids[] = $user->ID;
}

// WP_User_Query arguments
$args = array(
     'include' => $prof_ids,
);
```

I tried printing each variable to see where I'm going wrong, and these are their outputs:

```
$usernames = Array
$prof_ids = Array
$prof_id = user2
$user = 
$args = Array
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: @Otto Since user_login (user1) = id (1) and user_login (user2) = id (2) I need the user ID's to be produced as `'include' => array( 1, 2),`, but it's not doing it as expected. In other words, `$usernames = array( user1, user2 );` should produce `'include' => array( 1, 2),`. My full code works fine if I type in `'include' => array( 1, 2),`, but it does not work with this section of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `get_user_by()` has a small hiccup in it. It needs to be **login** rather than **user_login**

```
// Search these Usernames
$usernames = array('user1', 'user2');

// Fetch the User IDs
$prof_ids = array(); 
foreach ($usernames as $prof_id) {
    $user = get_user_by('login', $prof_id); 
    $prof_ids[] = $user->ID;
}

// WP_User_Query arguments
$args = array(
     'include' => $prof_ids,
);
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you!!